# Error NG0900 Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

with *ngFor i am able to render the data, but it throws this error

ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

**Here is my service method**

```
async getEditions(): Promise<Observable<Cigales>> {
    return this.http.get<Cigales>(url+"/candidates/editions", httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((getEditions: Cigales) => this.log('getEditions' + getEditions)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Cigales>('getEditions'))
    );
  }
```

**Here is my component method**

```
  editions: Cigale[] = [];

  async getEditions(): Promise<void> {
    await this.CigalesService.getEditions().then(res=> {
      res.subscribe(data => {
        this.editions = [];
        this.editions = data.content;
      })
    })
  }
```

**Here is my Cigales interface**

```
export interface Cigales {
  content: Array<Cigale>,
  pageable: pageable,
  last: string;
  totalPages: string;
  totalElements: string;
  size: string;
  number: string;
  sort: sort;
  first: string;
  numberOfElements: string;
  empty: string;
}

export interface Cigale {
  id?: string;
  eventName: string;
  eventStartDate: string;
  eventEndDate: string;
}

type sort = {
  empty: boolean,
  sorted: boolean,
  unsorted: boolean
}

type pageable = {
  sort: sort,
  offset: string;
  pageNumber: string;
  pageSize: string;
  paged: string;
  unpaged: string;
}
```

**Here is my component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of editions">
        <td>{{item.eventName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.eventStartDate}}</td>
        <td>{{item.eventEndDate}}</td>
        <td>
          <a class="d-inline" role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#application-modal"><i class="bi bi-clipboard"></i></a>
          <a class="d-inline" role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#application-modal"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Console.log(this.editions) and i get an array of two objects

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgI2C.png)

**EDIT :** I've tried Array.isArray(this.editions) and it returns true

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the error you are facing is related to the fact that you are trying to use an object as the data source for *ngFor directive instead of an array.

Secondly, try to assign data to this.editions like:

```
async getEditions(): Promise<void> {
  await this.CigalesService.getEditions().then(res=> {
    res.subscribe(data => {
      this.editions= [...data.content];
    })
  })
}
```

Also, I would advise you to avoid using Promises in your Angular applications and instead make your code more reactive by leveraging Subscriptions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i've tried as you said but it produce the same error

Answer (score 0):

try this:

service method:

```
getEditions(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(url+"/candidates/editions", httpOptions).pipe(
     map(data => data.content)
);
```

}

component method:

```
getEditions(): void {
  this.CigalesService.getEditions().subscribe(res => {
    this.editions = [...res];
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it produce the same error

Comment: can you share console.log(this.editions) in your component method?

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgI2C.png)

Comment: Define a variable named initialized and set it to true after editions is initialized in the method and in the html code, put that in ng-container with the initialized condition and put the rest of the code in it. Is the same problem still there?

Comment: Yes still same problem

Comment: Are you using the *ngFor directive in other places within your application? If so, could you provide an example in StackBlitz?

Comment: The only way is to upload the code in Stack Blitz and of course learn how to simulate the same code in Stack Blitz.